# Anomaly detection on Syslog

Tags: machine-learning, pattern-matching, syslog

I wonder , if someone know the open source anomaly detection algorithm on computer log ? For an example , computer log look like as mentioned below :

"value UL-CCCH-Message ::= { integrityCheckInfo { messageAuthenticationCode 0, rrc-MessageSequenceNumber 0 }, message cellUpdate : { u-RNTI { srnc-Identity 232, s-RNTI 178710 }, startList { { cn-DomainIdentity ps-domain, start-Value 58 } }, am-RLC-ErrorIndicationRb2-3or4 FALSE, am-RLC-ErrorIndicationRb5orAbove FALSE, cellUpdateCause cellReselection, rb-timer-indicator { t314-expired FALSE, t315-expired FALSE }, measuredResultsOnRACH { currentCell { modeSpecificInfo fdd : { measurementQuantity cpich-Ec-N0 : 24 } } } }"

there is way , i could extract features from logs and apply anomaly detection on time series data but there is also one other way is that i will discover general pattern from log automatically and make rule/ criteria , if future log belong to general pattern , if not not then its anomaly . I want to know any algoritm to find automatic pattern discovery in logs .

Please share your ideas, if you have expertise in it.

Thanks 
Kind Regard, 
Sash

Comment: Can you expand on this? Can you describe exactly what you are looking for? Can you provide what you have found from searching the web? Have you researched at all?

Comment: i updated mu question now.

Comment: [archelle16](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7995437) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66272965) saying "I think you're looking for Elasticsearch's Anomaly detection using categorization
Here have a look https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/machine-learning/6.8/ml-configuring-categories.html"

Answer (score 2):

The direct answer to your question is - there are no open-source anomaly detection algorithm for computer log you presented(I guess the output is from telecom BTS, right?).

There are just anomaly detection algorithms - like Frequent Pattern Mining, k-means and etc.

Mostly, all anomaly detection algorithms are available as a part of programming packages for Python, R, Matlab and etc. Hence, we don't need to look for an algorithm.

Now I think your real question is:

> there is way , i could extract features from logs and apply anomaly detection on time series data but there is also one other way is that i will discover general pattern from log automatically and make rule/ criteria , if future log belong to general pattern , if not not then its anomaly . I want to know any algoritm to find automatic pattern discovery in logs .

There are no off-the-shelf systems that will do above. The best option that I can suggest is: use SumoLogic/Splunk or similar type of solution to for text-based searching. Those tools will help you in your issue. However, eventually, the accuracy of those anomalies will become a problem.

Therefore, the answer is: **you need to build a custom ML system (with feature extraction+optimization+algorithm+visualization) to solve the problem of detecting anomalies in time-series BTS computer logs. And your deliverable (what exactly you are delivering - anomalies, insights, analytics) will have a significant influence on what algorithms, what features and what parameters you will use.**

I have been working with above for more than one and half years now, and I would really suggest you to start with small things - like text-based search software - it can be more than enough for daily tech support troubleshooting.

P.S. A small tip - have a look at how people build intrusion detection systems in cyber security - they are solving the same problem (normal vs abnormal anomaly, sequence based analysis, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

The following is approach based on this article: [Enterprise search](http://manmustbecool.github.io/MyWiki/papers/Enterprise%20search%20with%20development%20for%20network%20management%20system.pdf). and it is developed based on text-based search platform - Apache Solr

1. Grouping logs based on window, e.g. time windows
2. Calculate term statistics for each group or window. i.e. the feature extraction.
3. Apply general anomaly detection algorithm on the time series data (term statistics for different time windows)
4. Based on anomaly information to find anomaly log